# font color is always black when printing from office apps to windows fax

Tags: printing, fax

is there a way to print it as gray ?

**original word document:**

[image]

**Result from direct printing to windows fax:**

[image]

**Result from printing via acrobat pdf >> print to fax (print as image):**

[image]

smaple of problem with black background

**source**:

[image]

**result in fax:**

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to print colour & shades to fax? Faxes hate colours & shades, hence they print to black & white.

Comment: because i have gray/white fonts over black background and the result is black over black.

Comment: So… why are you trying to fax such unsuitable documents? You're working with 1980's technology, you need to treat it as such.